# Auto Login on debug ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to auto login for debugging purposes on an ASP.net core 2.1 application I've built.

Getting the Error :

> HttpContext must not be null.

The code below sits in the **Startup.cs** file

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider ServiceProvider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        CreateRoles(ServiceProvider).Wait();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            DeveloperLogin(ServiceProvider).Wait();
        }
    }


    private async Task DeveloperLogin(IServiceProvider serviceProvider){

        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
        var signInManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<User>>();

        var _user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync("test@gmail.com");

        await signInManager.SignInAsync(_user, isPersistent: false);

    }
```

This is an extension of sorts on another question I asked a while back about Windows Authentication on a Mac. Because of the nature of the application I had added Core Identity for role management even though the application still only uses Windows Auth.

Since I migrated to a Macbook for development I'm trying to autologin on build for debugging using the already existing Identity since there is no Windows Auth which is where the DeveloperLogin function fits in but I get the error mentioned above.

**StackTrace:**

```
    System.AggregateException: "One or more errors occurred. (HttpContext must not be null.)" 
---> System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}: "HttpContext must not be null."
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.get_Context()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, String authenticationMethod)
    at myApp.Startup.DeveloperLogin(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in /Users/user/Documents/Repositories/myApp/myApp/Startup.cs:135
```

Comment: and what is the stacktrace of the error? I can't see anthing related to httpcontext in the code

Comment: I've added the stacktrace. From some googling SignInManager.SignInAsync(user) results in a call to httpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, userClaimsPrincipal) and since the application is still starting up there is no HttpContext as yet.

Comment: Is there a way to invoke an HttpContext on startup and point the SignIn to that context? From my understanding since the code is still starting up so there wouldn't be a context as there hasn't been a request as yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `HttpContext`, it only exists during http request pipeline. There is no `HttpContext` in `Configure` method, you need to refer the code during middleware.

For using `Identity`, you need to use `app.UseAuthentication();`.

Follow steps below with sigin with `Identity`.

- Configure request pipeline.

  ```
      app.UseAuthentication();
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
          app.Use(async (context, next) =>
          {
              var user = context.User.Identity.Name;
              DeveloperLogin(context).Wait();
              await next.Invoke();
          });
      }

      app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
          routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });
  ```

  **Note:** you need to call `app.UseAuthentication();`, the order is import.
- `DeveloperLogin`

  ```
      private async Task DeveloperLogin(HttpContext httpContext)
  {

      var UserManager = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
      var signInManager = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>();

      var _user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync("Tom");

      await signInManager.SignInAsync(_user, isPersistent: false);

  }
  ```